# What are the different type of repos required for nuget package manager?

Tags: c#, .net, artifactory

I am creating the following repos in Jfrog Artifactory for the .Net project we are starting, and we are planning to use NuGet as our package manager

```
productname-nuget-snapshot
productname-nuget-release
productname-nuget-thirdparty
```

I want the know whether the above repos are enough or do we require more? while I am going through some existing repo names I got to know the following but not sure about their purpose with NuGet.

```
productname-nuget-staging
productname-nuget-local
productname-nuget-myd
productname-nuget-suo
productname-nuget-svs
```

Please guide me about the best practices to follow on this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first eloborate from Artifactory side, then you will be able to decide on the repositories.

Artifactory comes with 3 set of repositories.

1. Local repository (where you can push your local artifacts)
2. Remote repository (where you can pull from remote end point registries like docker hub)
3. Virtual repository (Its a combination of multiple local repositories and multiple remote repositories.

For a regular usage, a set of above 3 repositories are good enough.
But if you have development team

In complext/hybrid projects, such as the development, staging and release stages. Artifact promotion can be done in many different ways within Artifactory. From simple property tagging for lesser events (e.g. “passed test X”), to larger quality gates the artifact has passed through. For example from one repository to another repository. In traditional development models this may represent actual teams who own the software in different stages of its life cycle. You may have a “sandbox”, while the artifact is being tested by developers at their desks, and “dev” or “snapshot” for builds that are occurring out of the CI system in the initial build-on-commit. The artifact will then move to a “qa”, “preprod” or “staging” repository, and finally to a “release” or “prod” repository. When an artifact retires, or when it triggers certain regulatory requirements for retention, the artifact and possibly all its dependencies can move to “archive”. Visit [this page](https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-structuring-naming-artifactory-repositories/) for the complete details.

It is now your call, on how many repositories you want to create according to your need.